# How to read/access a filename with non-ascii characters

Tags: python, linux, character-encoding

I have the following file:

```
$ ls -l /var/tmp/attachment
-rw-rw-r-- 1 3103 king_kong 27136 Apr  7  2014 å·æ°£ç³»çµ±åæ°´éç¶­ä¿®.msg
```

When I try to list the file specifically, I get a file not found error:

```
$ ls -l /var/tmp/attachment/å·æ°£ç³»çµ±åæ°´éç¶­ä¿®.msg
ls: /var/tmp/attachment/å·æ°£ç³»çµ±åæ°´éç¶­ä¿®.msg: No such file or directory
```

Thus, I can't figure out how to rename this file to have a simpler filename (ascii chars only), like "example.msg".

Ideally, I'd like to read this file in Python. This is clearly not the way to do it:

```
>>> data = open(r'/var/tmp/attachment/å·æ°£ç³»çµ±åæ°´éç¶­ä¿®.msg', 'rb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/tmp/attachment/\xe5\xb7\xe6\xb0\xa3\xe7\xb3\xbb\xe7\xb5\xb1\xe5\xe6\xb0\xb4\xe9\xe7\xb6\xad\xe4\xbf\xae.msg'
```

Apart from getting the source to save the file with a different name, is there any way to "fix" the filename via command line in linux, or using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When on the shell, your terminal will be trying to translate the byte string to printable chars. It's possible some of the bytes aren't valid chars at all so copy-pasting them is useless.

The easiest was to deal with non-printable filenames on the shell is to use get a file's inode then use `find` to do something with it.

To get a file's inode:

```
ls -il
```

The first column is the inode. Pass this to find:

```
find . -inum <inode-number> -exec mv {} newfilename.msg \;
```

**In Python,** the trick is open a file with an odd name is to do a file list and pass the resulting string to `open`.

For example:

```
os.listdir('/var/tmp/attachment/')
```

Comment: I ended up listing the dir using os.listdir() then using shutil.copyfile() to rename it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem try

```
data = open(ru'/var/tmp/attachment/å·æ°£ç³»çµ±åæ°´éç¶­ä¿®.msg', 'rb')
```

Comment: I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when I use "ru"

Answer (score 0):

Such you have one file with '.msg' extension ,try

```
rename 's/.*/test.msg/' *.msg
```

Comment: That did not seem to change anything.

Comment: Oupps just remove -n parameter

Comment: Same result. The files did not change.

Comment: Do you get an error or nothing happens? try `sudo rename 's/.*/example.msg/' *.msg` in your `/var/tmp/attachment` directory.It works perfectly for me

Comment: I get no error. The command runs and returns me to the next line (prompt). The file remains unchanged. Also tried with sudo. Same result.